# If there is no attribute namespace in the data binding, intellisense will not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

There is a very simple bindingadapter function.

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("app:test")
fun testBind(v: View, test: Int) {
    //test...
}
```

If you apply this code in xml, it will usually look like this:

[image]

autocomplete function works fine, and xml does not print any warnings.

However, this bindingadapter function outputs a warning at compile time.

```
warning: Application namespace for attribute app:test will be ignored.
```

Many other posts say remove namepsace for this warning.

I removed the namespace from the bindingadapter function along with it.

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("test")
fun testBind(v: View, test: Int) {
    //test...
}
```

Doing so will not print out the warning at compile time.

But this time, xml prints a warning.

[image]

Also, when the namespace exists, the autocomplete function that worked normally does not work at all.

Of all the methods I've tried, the only way to resolve all two warnings is to specify the namespace as android.

is there any other way? android namespace seems to be a misunderstanding as this is a basic binding feature in Android, not a custom binding function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using single argument in binding adapter method, remove namespace in @BindingAdapter(...) string, after that add bind: namespace before calling string in xml.

```
 @JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("icon")
fun setImage(view: ImageView, imageID: Int) {
}
```

and `bind:icon="@{vm.iconID}"`

If I'm using several attributes it's not worked.